# error typescripts TS 2532 objeto posiblemente indefinido

Tags: typescript, react-native

estoy manejando un token en mi backend para login y el crud pero me da error en el config.headers, el error dice que no está definido, estoy usando react native con axios y async storage

```
TTApi.interceptors.request.use(
async(config) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if ( token ) {
        config.headers['x-token'] = token;
    }
    return config;
}
```

);

Comment: ¿Qué línea te marca el error?

Comment: Muestra el mensaje de error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: la linea que me da error es config.headers['x-token'] = token; esta linea es un middleware que utiliza un token del backend para dejar que el usuario cree o actualice en la base de datos, el error especifico es Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: Podrías poner una captura de pantalla con el error, no estoy seguro si el error se refiere al objeto `config` o al valor de la variable `token`. ¿Qué es lo que contiene `token`, un objeto o un valor plano?

Comment: Buen día se solucionó re instalando el node modules de la carpeta del proyecto, gracias